SQLSTATE[22032]: <<Unknown error>>: 3140 Invalid JSON text: "Invalid value." at position 0 in value for column 'products.product_active_matterials'
I got this error while inputing data through form in my laravel project that some column in database having json datatype.

Below are my inputed value

and here is my table structure.

ProductController.php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Management;

use App\Core\BaseResponse;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Services\ProductService;
use Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\Product;

class ProductController extends Controller
{

    protected $service;

    public function __construct(ProductService $service)
    {
        $this->service = $service;
    }

    public function index()
    {
        return view('backend.product.index');
    }

    public function table(): JsonResponse
    {
        $users = $this->service->getTable();

        return BaseResponse::json($users);
    }

    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        try {
            # get post parameters
            $post_parameters = $request->input();

            # create new equipment
            $this->service->store($post_parameters);

            # return response
            return BaseResponse::json([
                'success' => 1,
                'message' => "Success to create new product {$post_parameters['product_name']}"
            ]);
        }
        catch (\Exception $e) {
            return BaseResponse::json([
                'success' => 0,
                'message' => $e->getMessage(),
                'data' => $post_parameters
            ]);
        }
    }
}

ProductService.php
<?php

namespace App\Services;

use App\Libraries\NanoId;
use App\Models\Product;
use App\Repositories\ProductRepository;

class ProductService
{

    protected $repository;

    public function __construct()
    {
        // Add your constructor logic here
        $this->repository = new ProductRepository();
        
    }

    public function getTable()
    {
        $product = $this->repository->getTable();

        return $product;
    }

    public function store(array $data)
    {
        $checkProductName = $this->repository->getProductName($data);
        if (!empty($checkProductName))
            throw new \Exception('Product Already Registered');

        # generate id
        $nano_id_library = new NanoId();
        $id = $nano_id_library->generateId(false);
        # prepare insert parameters
        $insertParameters = [
            'product_id' => $id,
            'product_code' => $data['product_code'],
            'product_name' => $data['product_name'],
            'product_active_matterials' => $data['product_active_matterials'],
            'product_group' => $data['product_group'],
            'product_pest_target' => $data['product_pest_target'],
            'product_dossage_min' => $data['product_dossage_min'],
            'product_dossage_max' => $data['product_dossage_max'],
            'product_uom' => $data['product_uom'],
            
        ];
        
        $opr = $this->repository->store($insertParameters);

        return $opr;
    }

    public function getById(string $id): object
    {
        return $this->repository->getById($id);
    }
}

product.js
$('#btn-save').on('click', function (e) {
    $('#btn-save')[0].setAttribute('data-kt-indicator', 'on');
    HELPER.block();

    // Disable button to avoid multiple click
    // $('#btn-save')[0].disabled = true;
    if (validator) {
        validator.validate().then(function (status) {

            if (status == 'Valid') {
                // Simulate form submission. For more info check the plugin's official documentation: https://sweetalert2.github.io/
                let data = $('#form-add-new-user').serializeArray();

                $.ajax({
                    url: BASEURL + "/management/product/" + ($('#product_id').val() ? "update" : "store"),
                    type: $('#product_id').val() ? "PUT" : "POST",
                    data: data,
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function(response) {
                        if (response.success !== 1) {
                            errorAlert(response.message);
                        }
                        else {
                            successAlert(response.message);
                            $(`[data-bs-dismiss="modal"]`).trigger("click");
                            init();
                        }
                    },
                    error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                        errorAlert('Something went wrong!');
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }

    HELPER.unblock()
});

Product.php(models)
<?php

namespace App\Models;

// use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;

use App\Traits\DrawTable;
use App\Traits\Loggable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Concerns\HasUuids;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasOne;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Laravel\Sanctum\HasApiTokens;
use Spatie\Activitylog\LogOptions;
use Spatie\Activitylog\Traits\LogsActivity;
use Spatie\Permission\Traits\HasRoles;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class Product extends Authenticatable
{

    use HasFactory, LogsActivity, HasUuids, Loggable, DrawTable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array<int, string>
     */
    protected $table = 'products';

    protected $fillable = [
        'product_id',
        'product_code',
        'product_name',
        'product_active_matterials',
        'product_group',
        'product_pest_target',
        'product_dossage_min',
        'product_dossage_max',
        'product_uom',
    ];

    protected $casts = [
        'product_active_matterials' => 'array',
        'product_pest_target' => 'array',
    ];

    public function getActivitylogOptions(): LogOptions
    {
        return LogOptions::defaults()
            ->logOnly(['*'])
            ->dontSubmitEmptyLogs()
            ->useLogName('products');
    }
}

already looking for some resolve in eloquent laravel docs, but all the docs explain when we declared it inside the file, not with userinput.

What is the value of product_active_matterials when you're trying to insert it? Is there more to the error message, such as the insert query?

the value is "soil, water" its a multiple value, and i want it to stored it in json inside my database, there's no such insert query error i suppose.
